# I'm getting a No Line Found error code via reading a text file

Tags: java

Odd error i'm getting. "No Line found". I tried commenting out my sem variable thinking that was the issue, however no dice. I have tried commenting out my String elements to see if those were the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

The error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
at Driver2.main(Driver2.java:27)

The Txt File:
**Kimberly Signwell
Sophomore
EDUC
3
Don Boss
Freshman
CPSC
1
Mayble Lently
Junior
MATH
6**

Each element has their own line. The error seems to say that I don't have a third line, however, the txt file has more than 3 lines.
**public class Driver2
{

```
private static Student [] students = new Student[100];
private static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    
    FileReader file = new FileReader("students.txt");       
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
            
    int i = 0;

        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {   
            String l1 = in.nextLine();
            
            String l2 = in.nextLine();
            String l3 = in.nextLine();
            int sem = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
        
            students[i++] = new Student(l1, l2, l3, sem);   
        
        }

    runMenu();
    
    System.out.printf("Program Finished");
    
}**
```

Comment: You need to post the actual stack trace containing the error message when you run your program. "No line found" is likely to actually be a "no such element" exception, but since you didn't post the actual message, it's hard to say. You also need to post a sample of your input file. Chances are, it doesn't contain what you think it should contain.

Comment: Thanks. I added clarifying details @MarsAtomic

Comment: The error you say you're getting doesn't seem consistent with the evidence. Look at your input file. You take a string, a string, another string and then you expect an int, but you actually have "EDUC", which is another string. You should be seeing InputMismatchException, not NoSuchElementException. Is the full line "EDUC" or is it "EDUC 3"? You're leaving something out here, because what you say you see isn't what you should be seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the `hasNextLine()` condition is checking for a single next line, but in the body of the loop, you are checking for the next four lines, which might give an error because if the program has reached suppose the second last line of the text file, the loop will execute because you do have another line of data, but the body of the loop demands for multiple lines of data...

The `nextLine()` function moves the cursor to the next line *every time* it is called, and not just once. Try watching some tutorials or reading docs for more understanding [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())